# Return row from isolated transaction using psql 10.9 and sqlalchemy with python3.7

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, transactions, python-3.7

In my use case I want to process many documents (100 mil) stored in a psql table in parallel. To prevent every worker from processing the same document concurrently I implemented a queue table. The algorithm for each worker is...

1. Pick a document whose id is not present in the queue table yet
2. Insert an entry into queue table with a reference to that specific document (id) and status=in_progress(0)
3. Process document
4. Update entry in queue table (status=done(1))
5. Go back to 1.

To do so I came up with a isolated transaction query:

```
BEGIN;
WITH TMP AS (SELECT id FROM documents WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT reference_id FROM queue) LIMIT 1)
  INSERT INTO queue (reference_id, status) SELECT (SELECT id FROM TMP), 0 RETURNING reference_id;
COMMIT;
```

Using psql cli this statement returns:

```
BEGIN
 reference_id 
------------
         42
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
COMMIT
```

Works like a charme.

But when I use it within a script written in python3.7 using sqlalchemy I won't get my row out of this transaction:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgres://db:db@localhost:5432/db')

transaction = '''
BEGIN;
WITH TMP AS (SELECT id FROM documents WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT reference_id FROM queue) LIMIT 1)
  INSERT INTO queue (reference_id, status) SELECT (SELECT id FROM TMP), 0 RETURNING reference_id;
COMMIT;
'''

with engine.connect() as con:
    row = con.execute(transaction)
    print(row.first())
```

The last row raises ...

`sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.`

Can I access that `reference_id` from within the isolated transaction? Or even better the variable `TMP`?

Comment: When using sqlalchemy it is best to use it's own notation and not to execute raw transactions.

Comment: According to [sqlalchemys offical documentation on transactions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html) it would mean to create a new session with each transaction. Is that efficient?

Comment: I think you can get around that if you load all problematic documents and add them in one session.

Comment: Can you define `all problematic documents`?

Comment: I meant all the documents you want to reference.

Comment: I'm a little confused. There are 100 million documents in the table `documents`. There 0 entries in the table `queue`. For each document to process one entry needs to be added to table `queue`. In the end the table `queue` holds 100 million rows - one for each document. The transaction is needed to prevent each runner from trying to process a document that is being processed already. There are no problematic documents.

Comment: @tharndt "it would mean to create a new session with each transaction"  Since it uses a built-in connection pool, this should be efficient.

Comment: @jjanes Yes. True. The problem with [sqlalchemys offical documentation on transactions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html) is just that it does not lock the table `queue` or the relevant row of the table `queue`. This leads to many many parallel try-excepts as all worker try to perform the same INSERT into table `queue` but just one is able to do so. While this one is busy the rest tries again with the next document leading to a "1 pass, rest fails" situation. It should be a real isolated transaction.

Comment: @tharndt the concurrency issue you describe is fundamental to your query.  It is independent of sqlalchemy (and certainly independent of sqlalchemy's *documentation*).  You should look at a real existing queueing solution, rather than trying to roll your own.  This is just the start of your problems, as your query will perform abysmally once "queue" is no longer tiny--for more than one reason.

Comment: @jjanes Thanks. You're right of course. A colleague told me the same and recommended this [article](https://tnishimura.github.io/articles/queues-in-postgresql/) about queues in psql